# Swift 3 - How do I display borders on my camera view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I am trying to figure out how to display these borders on a camera feed as below:

[image]

I have a custom camera view that I managed to follow some tutorials for but I'd like to customize some borders to help the user frame the picture that I want them to take.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the border as a `UIImageView`. Make an `@IBOutlet` like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var focusIndicator: UIImageView
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` function of your viewController add this.

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: focusIndicator)
```

keeping in mind to change `focusIndicator` to whatever you named it

Hope this helps you

Comment: ah, so should the border be an image?  How does that scale to other device sizes?

Comment: @noblerare yes that is how I would do it if you add a `UIImageView to the viewController and add the constraints it will automatically scale to the sizes of other devices

Comment: For future readers: I went into my favorite vector image creator program (e.g. Illustrator, Sketch, Photoshop), made the borders, set everything else transparent and exported a PNG.  Then, I imported that image into Xcode and dragged an ImageView onto the ViewController in the storyboard to set the dimensions of how I want the borders to look.  Then I did: `borders.image = //name of PNG` and `self.view.insertSubview(borders, aboveSubview: cameraView)`

Comment: @noblerare you could have set the UIImageView image from the attributes inspector instead of using borders.image = "whatever your image name is" just letting you know